# Using FORFILES to move files to Archive folder, tilde in directory name

Tags: batch-file

I am attempting to use FORFILES for the purposes of archiving files and I have all of the information from the help and examples that work except for this one piece.  In my network path, someone in their infinite wisdom used the tilde (~) character as the directory name, ie  y:\dept\deptname\~~~ DOWNTIME FOLDER ~~~\data\   and I have another folder below the \data\ folder called archive.  I am trying to move all files in \data\ older than 30 days to the archive folder.  As long as I move my command line to the directory in the batch file I am creating, I don't have to reference the directory completely to get it to give me back the @path or @relpath in an echo statement but I cannot reference the full directory path to "move" the files to the \archive path in the second half of the FORFILES statement.  Any suggestions on how to 'replace' the tilde in the directory path?
 Here is my full statement:

```
FORFILES /D -30 /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE move @file y:\dept\deptname\~~~ DOWNTIME FOLDER ~~~\data\archive"
```

This just gives back an error Access is denied, but yet I have access to this network location for both the directory \data\ and subdirectories below.

Comment: You need to put quotes around file paths that have spaces.  Should always use them regardless of needing them.

Comment: Your issue is the space characters, not the tildes. To doublequote the path, _as those are classed as special characters inside the enclosing doublequotes_, use the hexadecimal code in 0xHH format, i.e. `0x22Y:\dept\deptname\~~~ DOWNTIME FOLDER ~~~\data\archive0x22`. _The information about this is clearly documented in the usage information, `ForFiles /?`_. You may also wish to use, `Move`'s `/Y` option.

Comment: Thank you, Compo.  That explained a lot.  I was missing that piece in the information about the Hex characters.   I had the quotes before but that didn't work but the Hex does.